# If we declare structure with all optional values, what is the size of the structure in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, structure

For example i have created one structure with all optional values. Then what is the size of the structure in swift. How can we calculate the size of the structure in swift?

Comment: `Optional` is an `enum` type. You'll find a detailed description of the layout of all Swift types at https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
struct Structure {
    //Some properties here
}

let size = MemoryLayout<Structure>.size
```